# Can I send login credentials securely to a server that uses SSL with HttpClient?

Tags: java, security, ssl, httpclient

My app uses HttpClient to login to a website that uses SSL (https://site.com/login.php). I recently got a message from them saying that my app should communicate with their website more securely.

I have read that httpclient supports SSL, but i am not sure what I need in order to POST login credentials and login to their website securely.

Do I just need to ask them for a public key or is there more to it?

Comment: You don't have to do anything except changing `http` to `https`.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz i am ready posting to the https url but what about the data that i am sending before it gets to the https server. the data is unencrypted

Comment: @user521180: What exactly does 'before' mean?

Comment: When you are connecting through https all bytes of the transmission are encrypted, including request headers and parameters. Not a single bit goes unencrypted.

Comment: @home before it reaches their secure server. I mean if someone were to listen to the connection they'll see the password that i am sending the server unencrypted

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz but i am posting to the https server before before the username and password are encrypted. if they get intercepted before reaching the https server they'll be plain text no?